# Eclipselink - what causes a long response time after the message “reconnecting to external connection pool”

Tags: mysql, eclipselink

I am re-posting a question from the eclipse link users mailing list since it's not clear to me where there is more activity (sorry for the spam).

I see in my application log an intermittent behavior where after I see the message “reconnecting to external connection pool” it takes very long time (15 and 30 minutes in 2 cases I noticed) until the thread is continuing with its activity and fails with OEF – obviously because so much time passed.
In other cases I see an immediate response and I am trying to figure out how to find the cause for the long response time –

- Is it a network problem?
- Maybe my connection pool is too small?
- Maybe the container that is hosting me can’t allocate more threads?
- Maybe…?

As you can see I am grasping here

Currently I am working up from the code of org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(AbstractSession)

I am using

- EclipseLink 2.4.2M3
- Spring 3.1.2
- Jetty 8.1.8
- DB is MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution we found to the problem.

1. Basically the problem was that we didn't have in our connection pool a definition to close connection if they are idle for X time
2. then we would have picked up once in a while a connection that we thought was open but it was already closed by the OS
3. So when we tried accessing the OS with a connection that was already closed - it took 15 minutes until we got a timeout

**bottom line - make sure you close idle connections**